# Is it possible to write this nested for loop as an apply function?

Tags: r

I have a nested for loop that is taking absolutely forever to run. The code is for running through 10 hidden units for a neural networks model fitting. I have always understood that apply functions are much faster but have not been able to implement them for more complicated tasks. I was wondering if anyone could guide me with their expertise to see if my code below is able to be run with apply functions. Thank you!

Here,

"data.file" is a list of size 10. Each element in the list is a data frame with dimensions 3067 x 58.

"test" is a data frame with dimensions of 1534 x 58

```
for(k in 1:10){
    mis.err <- NULL 
    for(i in 1:10){
            nett <- nnet(as.factor(type) ~., data = data.file[[i]], size = k, rang=0.7, maxit = 110)
            yhat <- predict(nett, test, type="class")
           tab <- table(yhat, as.factor(test[,58]))
           err <- 1-sum(diag(tab))/sum(tab)

           if (i == 1) mis.err <- err else me <- rbind(mis.err, err)

     }

     table <- rbind(table, c(k, mis.err))

 }
```

My end output desire is a 10 by 2 table with the k values on the first column and the mis.err values on the second column.

Thank you!

Comment: It would be far easier to tell if it is possible, if you also presented sample input and desired output data.

Comment: This would be a fairly useless exercise. It won't be easier to understand and won't be any faster.

Comment: `for` loops are not slower than `*apply`.  If you run `Rprof` I bet you'll find that the `nnet` calls are taking up 90% of the execution time so unless you can reduce the number of calls, you're SOL.